# AngularJs How to sanitize URL in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

I was wondering if there is a programmatic way of sanitizing (user provided) URLs in AngularJs 1.5. I know there is $sanitize service, which is for sanitizing HTML but I can't find something that would work for URL.

Sample Good URL:

```
http://www.somedomain.com
```

Sample Dangerous URL:

```
javascript:document.write('Time for some fun');
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to use urls for? Try to bind a dangerous url to href and see what happens.

Comment: When I bind it to an <a> element and try to click on the element, then URL is automatically sanitized by Angular and I basically end up on a new tab. But in my case, I need to sanitize the URL programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is undocumented [`$$sanitizeUri` service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js) that does this. It's basically [a function that adds `unsafe` prefix to supplied URL](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.6/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js#L62-L70). There's no need to use it for URLs are bound to `href` like

```
<a href="{{url}}">
```

because this is already done by compiler (`$$sanitizeUri` is used there).

For malformed URLs in general it may be better to process them by hand and possibly add `http://` if it doesn't contain acceptable (http/https) protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I don't want to create a <a> element just so I can use the $$sanitizeUri service. Your answer did help me with the js code I can use to test for dangerous URLs, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up performing the following regex test (inspired from [$$sanitizeUri service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js)) on the URLs and then performing a special operation whenever the check failed.

```
function navigateToUrl(url) {
    var safeWhiteListRegex = \^(https?|ftps?|file?):\/\/\gi;
    if (!safeWhiteListRegex.test(url)) {
        // url = ...;
    } else {
        $window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

Along the way, one of my friends also discovered the [@braintree/sanitize-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@braintree/sanitize-url) Node Module, which I also think is something people can use for situations like this.